# Python 301 POST

Tags: python, redirect, post, python-requests, csrf

So basically I'm trying to make a request to this website - https://panel.talonro.com/login/ which is supposed to be `301 redirect`.

I send data as I should but in the end there is no Location header in my request and status code is `200` instead of `301`.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help

```
def do_request():
    req = requests.get('https://panel.talonro.com/login/').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
    csrf = soup.find('input', {'name':'csrfKey'}).get('value')
    ref = soup.find('input', {'name':'ref'}).get('value')
    post_data = {
        'auth':'mylogin',
        'password':'mypassword',
        'login__standard_submitted':'1',
        'csrfKey':csrf,
        'ref':ref,
        'submit':'Go'
}

    post = requests.post(url = 'https://forum.talonro.com/login/', data = post_data, headers = {'referer':'https://panel.talonro.com/login/'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now `push_data` is in `do_request()`, so you cannot access it outside of that function.

Instead, try this where you return that info and then pass it in:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def do_request():
    req = requests.get('https://panel.talonro.com/login/').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
    csrf = soup.find('input', {'name':'csrfKey'}).get('value')
    ref = soup.find('input', {'name':'ref'}).get('value')
    post_data = {
        'auth':'mylogin',
        'password':'mypassword',
        'login__standard_submitted':'1',
        'csrfKey':csrf,
        'ref':ref,
        'submit':'Go'
        }
    return post_data

post = requests.post(url = 'https://forum.talonro.com/login/', data = do_request(), headers = {'referer':'https://panel.talonro.com/login/'})
```

Comment: It wasn't a problem, I was doing it all inside a function and printing there, then just calling it from the main function. The problem still persists - I don't have Location header, I don't get 301 status code  even tho post data is right. Never dealed with 301 POST requests before and now I'm stuck